# Install4j Laucher app fails to run if Windows path has an ampersand (&)

Tags: windows, install4j

We're using install4j to bundle our Application. When installing on Windows, if the user installs to a path that contains an ampersand (&) character, the Launcher fails. (NOTE: We've been using install4j for more than a year now with no other known path issues except for this one)

We're using a Launcher to wrap a JAR archive as an executable.

We discovered this issue when we created a Windows account with an ampersand (&) in it (for example: Bill&Ted). We then logged in as this user and ran the install4j installer and asked it to install to the current users Desktop (for example: The Installation path would be C:\Users\Bill&Ted\Desktop\MyApp). The Launcher does not execute properly.

Opening a command prompt and running the Launcher manually doesn't say or do anything (fails quietly). Is there some way we can enable debug info for this?

However, running the java command (for example: C:\Users\"Bill&Ted"\Desktop\MyApp\jre\bin\java.exe -jar C:\Users\"Bill&Ted"\Desktop\MyApp\images\myapp.jar) does work. NOTE: I needed to add the quotes around "Bill&Ted", without them, this command also fails.

My suspicion is that the Windows paths are not being delimited properly within the Launcher. I'm not sure if this is something I can control/set or is it an issue within the Launcher code itself.

Configuration:
How my Launcher is configured:

1) Select Launcher Type = Generated Launcher

2) Executable Info = GUI Application, File Set: Default File Set, Directory: blank, All checkbox CHECKED with '.' being the "Change Working Directory to:"

2b) Advanced options: Configure Redirection: Redirect stderror checked and set to error.log, Windows version info resource: Nothing selected. Execution level: As Invoker, Menu Integration: with standard name.

3) Define Launcher Icon: Add icon to launcher set with icons in .\images\XXXX.png (we have 3 icons 16x16, 32x32 and 48x48). Generate from cross-platform image files is selected

4) Java invocation: VM Parameters: -Dapple.awt.UIElement=true, Allow VM passthrough parameters is CHECKED. Class Path: Archive: blah.jar, Arguments: -profile "LIVE" -loglevel INFO

4b) Advanced options: Native Libraries - Nothing - Preferred VM - Default VM

5) VM options file: Copy template file with explanations for user. Overwrite mode: Never

6) Splash Screen: No Splash Screen

Comment: I cannot reproduce that with a user "Bill&Ted". The only restriction is that exclamation marks (!) cannot be used in user names, because Java cannot handle that. Do you use the latest version of install4j?

Comment: Ingo, thanks for checking on that for me. Is there any way I can gather more diagnostic info? Am I correct in my assumption above regarding how the Launchers fundamentally work? I'll recheck my install4j configuration to see if there anything suspicious.

Comment: Ingo, just some more information about how my Launcher is configured:

Comment: Ingo, forgot to mention, I am running v5.1.6

Comment: You can start the executable from the command line with the argument /create-i4j-log. This will generate a detailed log file.

Comment: Ingo, looks like I was wrong with regards to the Launcher itself. The problem seems to revolve around my running the Launcher from the installer itself. I am probably not delimiting the Windows path properly myself.

Comment: Do you use the "Execute launcher" action or the "Run executable" action?

Comment: We are using the "Execute Launcher" action to start it at installation.

Comment: Ingo, not sure if it is a fault on my side. I reviewed the install4j configuration for starting a Launcher and there isn't any path information to set/provide. Is this scenario something you can test and verify?

Comment: The problem may be the intermediate batch file that is used in this action. It is provided for backwards compatibility with Win9x which is really quote obsolete and will be removed in install4j 6. Until then I don't have a workaround, I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks Ingo, is there an release timeframe (approximate or otherwise) for install4j v6? I assume that other characters may also be problematic.

Comment: It's planned for Q1/2014